# CSS: Background Image

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, how can I make it so that the background image of a page will not move (will stay stationary) when I scroll down a page?  The text and other elements should obviously move, but I want the background image to stay constant.

Also using CSS, how can I fit the background image into the users full screen?  For example, a background image that's 4000 px by 3000px obviously wont be completely displayed in the screens of most users, how can I make it so that it is scaled down , and the entire background image will be shown on the user's screen?

Comment: Fixed background-image + cover?

Comment: https://www.google.com/?q=css+background+image+fixed

Answer (score 2):

hey use this css rules (css3 property) : "cover"

```
html { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/4000x3000) no-repeat center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; /* Chrome and Safari */
  -moz-background-size: cover; /*  Firefox */
  -o-background-size: cover; /* Opera */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3BKJt/1/

Comment: This is not correct. All you need is **background-attachment: fixed** property. This itself prevents the background image from being scrollable.

Comment: Even the fiddle you have used makes use of  **background-attachment:fixed** property to produce this effect.

Comment: See this here->http://jsfiddle.net/q7df3/1/. The only difference between your fiddle and this fiddle is that the **background attachment** property value is different.

Comment: question was : how can I make it so that it is scaled down , and the entire background image will be shown on the user's screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55400/discussion-between-jmercier-and-satwik-nadkarny).

Answer (score 2):

```
body{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: stretch center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Use this code if you want the background stretched to fit the screen regardless of the size of your page. Solves the appearances of white empty zone spaces when resized at a certain range.

Answer (score 0):

You can target body or html

```
body {
            background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1000x1000');
            background-size: 100%;
            background-atttachment: fixed;
        }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyYL4/1/)

Answer (score -2):

If you want the background-image to not be scrollable, then no matter what image you place as the background, you need only one CSS property to set it as you want:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/dUZCb/2/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: question is :that's 4000 px by 3000px obviously won[...]